# How to estimate the number of DCU for a current serveless SQL Azure database

Tags: azure-sql-database, cost-management

I currently have a SQL Azure Database configured with the "serverless" setting.
It was ok at the beginning of the project because we had a lot of idle time and thanks to the autopause setting, we had good cost-efficiency.

But now we have more workload and it became costly to keep this serverless configuration.
We want to move to a "Standard" DCU billing and for this, we need to compute how many maximum DCUs we need to assign to the database.
Unfortunately, except if I missed it, there are no DCU metrics computed when the DB is in serverless mode.

I'm looking for a way to determine the number of DCUs I need to assign to my DB, any ideas?

Comment: I mean DTU instead of DCU...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are two types of Azure SQL Database purchasing model.

1. vCore based purchasing model
2. DTU based purchasing model

[image]

And as per this [official document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/database/serverless-tier-overview#purchasing-model-and-service-tier), **SQL Database serverless is currently only supported in the General Purpose tier on Generation 5 hardware in the vCore purchasing model.** That's the reason there is no DTU metrics computed when the DB is in serverless mode.

So now, when you are planning to switch to Standard DTU based purchasing model, you need to consider few metrics of your existing serverless model.

Calculate approx. IOPS for your current database. Standard DTU model provides 1-5 IOPS per DTU.

[DTU Calculator](https://dtucalculator.azurewebsites.net/) will be the main solution to estimate the DTUs requirement when we are migrating to DTU based Azure SQL Database. The main idea of this tool is capturing the various metrics utilization from the existing SQL Server that affects the DTUs and then it tries to estimate approximately DTUs and service tier in the light of the collected performance utilizations.